# Zend 2.2.4 formRow can't render č ć ž š đ

Tags: php, zend-framework2

Question is simple. How to render form with text element who have special charater ( like č ć ž š đ ) in MVC view with formRow ?

Code

```
echo $form->get('name')->getLabel();
```

displays corect characters, but when use code

```
echo $this->formRow($form->get('name'));
```

won't display label at all. Same is for values in text element. If values contain special characters ( like č ć ž š đ ) they won't be rendered.
I tried to add element with code

```
<form name="f">
name: čćž <input type="text" name="name" value="čćž"><br>
</form>
```

and everthing works fine.
So problem is with Zend formRow function. 
Is there anyone solve this ?

Comment: So, no idea of what your project encoding is, I guess :-?

Comment: When you try echo '<pre>'; print_r($form->get('name')->getValue()); exit; what output do you get?

Comment: Please have a look at [UTF-8 all the way through](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through). If you are using a framework and you have no idea of what encoding is, switching to UTF-8 is the easiest fix.